# How to install PhoneGap with Mac OS X Lion(10.7.3)?

Tags: macos, cordova

I have a Mac OS X Lion(10.7.3). Now I want to install PhoneGap in my XCode. My XCode version is 4.3.2.

**I followed the instruction** of installation from PhoneGap web site at the time of installation. But when I create one project it shows error as well as `www` folder also not created at the time of project creation.

According to the [**PhoneGap web site**](http://phonegap.com/start) to install I have to have Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6). Is it not possible to install PhoneGap with Lion(10.7.3) or I have to wait until the supported version comes up?

*Note: I am new with Xcode, Mac and PhoneGap.*

Answer (score 1):

You specify that **you are new to the technology**, for this, you should follow the tutorial, **step by step** and **read all points before doing anything** to your computer so you fully understand what you will do next.

You mention that the `www` folder is not even created, well, the startup tutorial is extremely explicit (*point 3.9*) and even has an image with the drop area:

> Next step is **IMPORTANT**! Drag the www folder into Xcode 4. You can't just drag the www folder into your app's folder. It needs to be dragged into Xcode 4!! In my case I would drag it and drop it on HiWorld shown below.

Regarding your mention if it can be installed in Lion, yes you can, startup shows the minimum requirement and it should be read as

> Intel-based computer with Mac OS X 10.6+